# How to efficiently select all rows having parent matching criterion?

Tags: sqlite

From a SQLite table having columns ID, IDofParent and Flavour, how with max. efficiency may I return the records for which any parent has Flavour = Lemon?

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQLite 3.8.3 or later, this can be done with a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE LemonsAndChildren AS (
    SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE Flavour = 'Lemon'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Child.* FROM ATable AS Child
        JOIN LemonsAndChildren AS Parent ON Child.IDofParent = Parent.ID
)
SELECT * FROM LemonsAndChildren
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution for versions lacking RECURSIVE?

Comment: Not in SQL, but step by step in your program.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is it possible to do in SQL without RECURSIVE when the max number of levels is known e.g. say three?

Comment: Yes, but that would be a different question.

Comment: I'd say "is" rather than "would" :) Thanks. I'll ask afresh.