# How to efficiently select all rows having parent matching criterion without RECURSIVE?

Tags: sqlite

On SQLite that does not have RECURSIVE, from a table having columns ID, IDofParent and Flavour, how with max. efficiency may I return the records for which the parent or grandparent has Flavour = 'Lemon'?

Comment: SQLite *does* have recursive queries: http://sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But not before version 3.8.3. ([earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25431938/11654))

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by looking up the (grand)parents with subqueries, and combining everything into a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
-- SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE Flavour = 'Lemon'
-- UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE IDofParent IN (
    SELECT ID FROM ATable WHERE Flavour = 'Lemon')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE IDofParent IN (
    SELECT ID FROM ATable WHERE IDofParent IN (
        SELECT ID FROM ATable WHERE Flavour = 'Lemon'))
```

(Repeating the queries cannot be avoided unless you execute the queries separately for each step, and insert the IDs from the last step into the next one.)